# Gomock not returning the expected value

Tags: go

I'm an experienced programmer but new to Go. I'm writing some logging tests, and for these purposes I've generated a mock of the `LogSink` class (using `mockgen`). Since that part is all auto-generated, I think we can assume nothing untoward there.

So here is my test code:

```
func TestLogging(t *testing.T) {
    ls := mock.NewMockLogSink(gomock.NewController(t))
    ls.EXPECT().Init(gomock.Any())
    const logLevel = 1
    ls.EXPECT().Enabled(gomock.Any()).AnyTimes().Do(func(level int) bool {
        return level <= logLevel
    })
    log.Set(logr.New(ls))
    ls.EXPECT().Info(gomock.Any(), "Foo").Times(1)
    log.Info("Foo")
    ls.EXPECT().Info(gomock.Any(), "Bar").Times(0)
    log.V(2).Info("Bar")
}
```

But this test fails, because the "Foo" log never gets called. I stepped through the code and found that my `EXPECT().Do()` code is being called as expected, and is returning `true`, but inside the mock code, it sees the result of `Logger.sink.Enabled()` as `false`!

What am I doing wrong? Is there a secret switch I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out `.Do()` *intentionally* ignores return values. Here's the documentation from the code:

```
// Do declares the action to run when the call is matched. The function's
// return values are ignored to retain backward compatibility. To use the
// return values call DoAndReturn.
```

Backward compatibility. Right. Bloody pit in the public domain, if you ask me...